# Bash Script does not Check Properly if Directory and File Exist

Tags: linux, bash

For some reason my `if condition` for a file and a directory not existing is not processing correctly. The script thinks that the file and directory exist when they do not.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
lockdir=/opt/someOtherDis/qa_test_lock
puppetlock=/var/opt/puppetLockDirs/agent_catalog_run.lock

if [ ! -f "$puppetlock" ] && [ ! -d "$lockdir"]; then
    #Get a url and grep it to get stuff
else
     su -c "echo ls puppetlock results: $(ls -lrt $puppetlock) and qa lock results: $(ls -lrt $lockdir) >> /var/log/dirStuff/test-qa-run.log" -m "someUser"
    su -c "echo $(date +\"%m-%d-%T\") Puppet or QA tests are running. Did not attempt to update artifact version. >> /var/log/dirStuff/test-qa-run.log" -m "someUser"
fi
```

I added the output of the `ls` to make sure I can see if puppet or the qa lock exists.

Here is the output of the log file, first check was when I run puppet manually so I could make sure things worked.

> 02-09-08:16:01 Puppet or QA tests are running. Did not attempt to
> update artifact version. ls puppetlock results: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root
> 5 Feb 9 08:27 /var/opt/lib/pe-puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock and
> qa lock results:
>
> 02-09-08:28:01 Puppet or QA tests are running. Did
> not attempt to update artifact version.
>
> 02-09-08:30:02
> app_versions.json has not been modified in the last 30 minutes ls
> puppetlock results: and qa lock results:
>
> 02-09-08:30:02 Puppet or QA
> tests are running. Did not attempt to update artifact version. ls
> puppetlock results: and qa lock results:
>
> 02-09-08:32:01 Puppet or QA
> tests are running. Did not attempt to update artifact version.

Comment: There should be a space between `"$lockdir"` and `]`, no?

Comment: @AlexP You are correct. No wonder I could not see it. Issue is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, seems like you meant to write:

```
if [ ! -f "$puppetlock" ] || [ ! -d "$lockdir" ]; then
```

Which (IMO) is more clearly written:

```
if ! test -f "$puppetlock" -a -d "$lockdir"; then
```

or

```
if ! { test -f "$puppetlock" && test -d "$lockdir"; } then
```

( Note that `!a || !b` is equivalent to `!(a && b)`, but not the same as `!a && !b`)